# C++ Iterators doing weird things

Tags: c++, iterator, stdstring

I might be completely stupid, but:

```
class Lexer {
    private:
        std::string::iterator start;
        std::string::iterator current;
        std::string source;
        int line;
        std::unordered_map<std::string, TokenType> keyword_table;

    public:
        Lexer(std::string program){
            this->source = program;
            this->start = program.begin();
            this->current = program.begin();
            
            this->line = 1;

            std::cout << std::distance(this->start, this->source.begin()) << std::endl;             
        }
        
        Token scan();      
};
```

When I print the distance between this->start and this->source.begin(), i get some wild number. Depending on the string that I've fed into the class, I've gotten 40 and even 448. I'm very confused on why this is.

I've tried changing variable names, switching between const_iterator and iterator, and printing this->source, program, this->start, etc. I'm very confused about why this problem is occuring. Btw the language is c++. Am I using std::distance wrong?

Comment: Warning: `std::string program` is passed by value and will expire at the end of the constructor. Those stored iterators will wind up referencing garbage.

Comment: You use unrelated iterators. The `start` and `current` iterators are for the `program` variable, which is unrelated to the `source` variable. You can't use the different iterators together.

Comment: Style note: use member initialization lists rather than `this->member = ...;`

Comment: All those `this->`s give me a headache. They're not needed.

Answer (score 4):

This line of code:

```
this->source = program;
```

Makes variable `source` contain **copy of data** of variable `program`. The fact that both variables contain the same string after that  does not mean that their iterators would be related at all. Your code could be simplified as this:

```
std::string s1 = "abc";
std::string s2 = s1;
std::cout << std::distance( s1.begin(), s2.begin() ) << "\n";
```

Which is invalid and leads to UB as you cannot calculate distance btw unrelated iterators as stated in [documentation:](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance)

> If InputIt is LegacyRandomAccessIterator, the behavior is undefined if first and last are neither reachable from each other.

(Despite the fact that you store dangled iterator in `start` and `current` after you ctor terminates which is a different issue)